# What are the general rules for comparing different data types in C?

Tags: c, comparison, types

Lets say I have the following scenarios:

```
int i = 10;
short s = 5;

if (s == i){
   do stuff...
} else if (s < i) {
  do stuff...
}
```

When C does the comparison does it convert the smaller data type, in this case short to int or does it convert the data type on the right to the data type on the left?
In this case int to short?

Comment: In C, the general rule is *please don't do that*. But the `short` would be promoted to an `int` in your example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is governed by the *usual arithmetic conversions*.  For simple cases, the general rule of thumb is that the type with "less" precision is converted to match the type with "more" precision, but it gets somewhat complex once you start mixing `signed` and `unsigned`.

In C99, this is described by section 6.3.1.8, which I include here for your convenience:

> - First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`,
>     the other operand is converted,
>     without change of type domain, to a
>     type whose corresponding real type is
>     `long double`.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`,
>     the other operand is converted,
>     without change of type domain, to a
>     type whose corresponding real type is
>     `double`.
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`,
>     the other operand is converted,
>     without change of type domain, to a
>     type whose corresponding real type is
>     `float`.
> - Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then
>     the following rules are applied to the
>     promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>       needed.
>   - **Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>       unsigned integer types, the operand
>       with the type of lesser integer
>       conversion rank is converted to the
>       type of the operand with greater rank.**
>   - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>       greater or equal to the rank of the
>       type of the other operand, then the
>       operand with signed integer type is
>       converted to the type of the operand
>       with unsigned integer type.
>   - Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>       represent all of the values of the
>       type of the operand with unsigned
>       integer type, then the operand with
>       unsigned integer type is converted to
>       the type of the operand with signed
>       integer type.
>   - Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>       corresponding to the type of the
>       operand with signed integer type.

I've highlighted the part that applies to your particular example.

The concept of *integer conversion rank* is defined in section 6.3.1.1, and it basically describes what you might expect (that types with less precision have a lower rank than types with more precision).

Answer (score 5):

From [Type Conversions](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/sx5g.html):

> The set of implicit conversions on page 44, though informally stated, is exactly the set to remember for now. They're easy to remember if you notice that, as the authors say, `` the `lower' type is promoted to the `higher' type,'' where the ``order'' of the types is

```
char < short int < int < long int < float < double < long double
```

That rule is easy to remember - "lower to higher" - but regarding signed and unsigned integer types it doesn't help much, those are nicely explained in Oli's post. But it's easy to remember and helps you in most cases.

Comment: How does `unsigned` fit there? is `-1` less than `2U`?

Comment: You're right, it's only part of the whole story. I'll take this into account.

Comment: +1: the signs really should be `<=` and, in C99, there's `long long int` to add to the confusion :)

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, C will not compare two values if they are not the same type and will never implicitly convert a variable to a type with less precision. In your sample code, the `short` is promoted to an `int`, which is equivalent to writing:

```
int i = 10;
short s = 5;

if ((int)s == i){
   do stuff...
} else if ((int)s < i) {
  do stuff...
}
```

This will do exactly what you expect, but the same is not true of signed/unsigned comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Datatypes are an abstraction of sorts .. as far as computer is concerned there are no `int` or `short`. There is memory and there is data.

When you say `int x`, you are saying to a computer "give me enough bytes to store an int", when you say `short y`, you are saying ... you guessed it.

`short`, as you would expect takes less bytes then an `int` and therefore may (and often does) contain data in the adjacent bytes. When comparing data of different types the issue is "will adjacent bits cause skewed results or not?"

Whenever you compare two different datatypes you really are comparing bits stored in two different locations. Max number of individual bits stored to represent the data need to be the same size for a comparison to work

[Casting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) is used to help with this.