# Comparison of two variables

Tags: c

I've just a great programming puzzle. Why is to same?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  unsigned int x = ULONG_MAX;
  char y = -1;   
  if (x == y) printf("That is same.");  

  return 0;
}
```

I think that unsigned int is converted to signed char, and thus it will be -1. It may be a standard for comparison of signed and unsigned type. I don't know...

Comment: Is this homework? Please use the [tag:homework] tag if so.

Comment: this is a dup of 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636793/what-are-the-general-rules-for-comparing-different-data-types-in-c

Comment: This is not a puzzle, this is totally expected behaviour if you know what two's complement arithmetic is.

Comment: How can someone voteup to homework? That is very difficult code why does it work like that. :-)

wildplasser: Maybe. I'm sorry, but I'm not oriented in standart. ;-)

Comment: BTW: You don't compare *variables*; you compare **values**. Values have types, too, partially inherited from the variables that they stem from; partially shaped by the operators that they are submitted to. The syntax probably says `expr == expr`, but expressions have values and types, too.

Answer (score 2):

In a tiff between `signed char` and `unsigned int`, `unsigned int` wins!

Its like this

[image: Size does matter]

Here `-1` will be converted to `unsigned int` which is `ULONG_MAX` and hence `if()` condition is true.

In C, size does matter. Variables are always converted to the highest size among them.

Comment: For completeness : since `y` is a `char`, which is signed, the value is sign-extended to the `unsigned int`, so we get a `11...11` - which is exact to `ULONG_MAX`.

Comment: Gives me values -1 and -1. Why?

Comment: @RePRO I think you are printing out the values using `printf` `%d`. And hence you see `-1`s. `%d` interprets the value as a signed integer which converts `ULONG_MAX` to `-1`. Number representation is the same but interpretations will differ. `==` favors `unsigned int` whereas `%d` favors `signed int`

Answer (score 1):

Many years ago, I learned a couple of things. One of them was compare like types.

I would either cast the `char` to an `unsigned int` if the `unsigned int`'s value is greater than `sizeof char`. Or cast the other way if the `unsigned int`'s values are to be restricted to a `sizeof char`. In that way, you are telling the compiler how you are comparing the values, and it will help maintainers as well.