# Negative Integer Comparisons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to compare two integers.  One is the `row` of an `NSIndexPath`, the other is the `count` of an `NSArray`.  The `row` is equal to 0 and the `count` is equal to 2.  I have them in an `if` statement as follows:

```
if([self.selectedSetpoint row] < ([self.theCategories count]-3))
{
    //Do true stuff
}
```

So by my math, the `if` statement should be false as I am comparing `0 < -1`.  However, I keep getting this statement coming through as true, and the block inside the `if` is being run.  I have tried to `NSLog` the values to make sure that I am not just getting the wrong value.  I placed this right BEFORE the `if` statement:

```
NSLog(@"%d",[self.selectedSetpoint row]);
NSLog(@"%d",[self.theCategories count]-3);
NSLog(@"%@",[self.selectedSetpoint row] < ([self.theCategories count]-3)?@"Yes":@"No");
```

and got this on the console:

```
2012-07-17 08:58:46.061 App[61345:11603] 0
2012-07-17 08:58:46.061 App[61345:11603] -1
2012-07-17 08:58:46.062 App[61345:11603] Yes
```

Any ideas why this comparison is coming up as true?  Am I misunderstanding something about comparing integers?

I have another if statement just above this one that compares

```
[self.selectedSetpoint row]<([self.theCategories count]-2)
```

Which is `0 < 0`, and it works fine (returns `NO`).  So I feel like there is some issue with the use of negative integers that I am not getting.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you meant -1 should be +1, you can use ABS(theCategories.count) so it returns absolute value of integer.

Comment: Is it not because you are comparing an NSUInteger with an NSInteger?

Comment: @EPyLEpSY no, I'm not trying to get the absolute value, I want it to compare 0 and -1.

Comment: @Luke I don't know, is count unsigned?  I figured if I got -1 in the log that I was going to get -1 in the comparison.

Comment: The index path's row is an int whereas the array's count is unsigned.

Comment: Hey @Luke, I didn't see your comment here until after I posted my answer. I'm pretty sure that's exactly the issue (I tested and reproduced his results with a fix being to cast as int). Perhaps you should post an answer too and get some rep out of it!

Comment: I don't usually have faith in my comments.... guess it's a bit late now with all the answers posted :)

Comment: @Luke, you are correct, had it been an answer I would have taken it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that the return of `count` is an **unsigned** integer, and subtracting more than it's magnitude, it underflows and becomes quite large. I have run some tests, and I get the same basic behavior as you (it *looks* like it's `-1`, and in certain contexts it *appears* to be working as expected... however it is clearly being underflowed in the context of the `if()` block.

Silly problem, but luckily there is a simple solution: Cast it in place in the if statement:

```
if([self.selectedSetpoint row] < ( (int)[self.theCategories count] -3 ))
{
    //Do true stuff
}
```

Comment: What a rookie mistake!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was going to propose an alternative solution - namely to avoid using subtraction and instead use addition on the other side of the equation:

```
if ([self.selectedSetpoint row] + 3 < [self.theCategories count])
{
    //Do true stuff
}
```

This sidesteps getting caught by these kind of underflow bugs, however it leaves another gotcha untouched... Namely the conversion rules referred to in the answer to this question: [What are the general rules for comparing different data types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636793/what-are-the-general-rules-for-comparing-different-data-types-in-c)

Quoting from an answer to that question, you see the C99 spec states:

- (when one operand is signed and the other unsigned) Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

So if you have a negative value for `[self.selectedSetpoint row] + 3` then the comparison will fail...

The other answers here have advocated casting (NSUInteger) to (NSInteger) - but note that this may cause overflow problems if your unsigned values are significantly massive.  For e.g:

```
(NSInteger) -3 < (NSInteger) 4294967289 == false...
```

Figuring there must be an easy way to solve this, I first came up with a hard way to solve it...

```
#define SafeLT(X, Y) \
({ typeof (X) _X = (X); \
   typeof (Y) _Y = (Y); \
( _X < (NSInteger) 0 ? (( _Y > 0) ? YES : _X < _Y ) : ( _Y < (NSInteger) 0 ? NO : _X < _Y));})
```

This should work regardless of how you mix NSUInteger and NSInteger, and will ensure that the operands are evaluated at most once (for efficiency).

By way of proof of correctness:

1. For `_X < (NSInteger) 0` to evaluate to True, _X must be NSInteger and < 0, so we check if _Y > 0.  The compiler will make the correct comparison here by evaluating the type of _Y.  If Y > 0 then by definition we return YES.  Otherwise we know both X and Y are signed and < 0 and can compare them safely.
2. However, if X is either NSUInteger or > 0 then we test Y to see if it is < 0.  If Y is < 0 then by definition we return NO.  So now we have X is NSUInteger or NSInteger > 0 and Y is NSUInteger or NSInteger > 0.  Since mixed comparisons will be promoted to NSUInteger we will have a safe conversion every time because there is no chance of underflow.

A simpler solution, however, would be to just typecast to a longer signed integer (iff your system has one):

```
#define EasySafeLT(X, Y) \
({ long long _X = (X); \
   long long _Y = (Y); \
   ( _X < _Y);})
```

Although this depends on having the larger type available so may not always be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

This does appear to be a case of comparing signed ints to unsigned ints. Your log statements will throw your assumptions because you are asking for the numbers to be printed signed.

```
NSLog(@"%d", -1); //Signed

-1;

NSLog(@"%u", -1); //Unsigned (tested on ios, 32 bit ints)

4294967295;
```

And then when you compare: `0 < 4294967295` certainly is true.

Casting as @ctrahey suggests should fix your problem:

```
if([self.selectedSetpoint row] < ( (int)[self.theCategories count] -3 ))
{
    //Do true stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about the log throwing me off.  You were a smidge late though to get the check!

Comment: I know! I was writing the answer as I saw the other one come through.  I only continued because of the extra information about NSLog. =]

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the `count` property is kind of `NSUInteger` and when you subtract a higher number from a smaller you won't get a less than zero number, you will get a very large positive number, it cause the strange behaviour.

try this way, and you would get the good result:

```
NSLog(@"%@",(NSInteger)[self.selectedSetpoint row] < ((NSInteger)[self.theCategories count]-3)?@"Yes":@"No");
```